# Why does Drupal run slow on localhost wamp?

Tags: 7

I'm using an i3 8GB RAM computer and Drupal is as slow as like using some cheap hosting provider.

So what could it be? I am using a freshly installed version of D7 and just browsing through site, going to Reports takes some time and I am not even talking about clearing cache or running cron.

Also using Drush via Git Bash also runs commands slow, like simply 'drush dl libraries' and then enabling it takes like 10 seconds and I am on 100MBit line.

I did some changes to php.ini file like memory_limit = 2G and etc. but it's as slow as if it was 128M.

Comment: Have you looked at output from Yslow, Firebug Network information.

WAMP is not a production system -- I'm sure you know this. Alternatively, install like APC.

Comment: i might be due to your systems huge cache data,
if you are using any os of microsoft try to use ccleaner tool,
this will remove all old cached data further more you can also use disk cleanup utility present in microsoft os.
ihis will boost your susyem performance.

Comment: I don't know if that's the problem cuz I just installed Acquia Dev Desktop and it runs very fast as it should be. And that's what I am using now for Drupal dev.

Comment: This question has been addressed before here. https://groups.drupal.org/node/211778

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installed Acquia Dev Desktop, runs smooth ant fast. Wamp is not production system.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the performance difference between running Drupal on a *NIX system VS Windows is really noticeable.

If you can, try running it on some Linux distro, either as a dual boot or virtual machine. Not only it will run faster, but it be closer to the deployment environment and help you spend less time on preparing/testing it for launch.

Answer (score 0):

i too have faced same problem with wamp server..

I have solved by re-installing wamp server and enabled module_deflate module in Apache server.

This will do..

Comment: This might do, but does not answer the core of the problem - something was happening, and stopped to after reinstall, but it would be good to know what was the real cause.